# How to customise Safari OCR?

Tags: macos, safari, ocr

How can I make macOS Safari OCR:

- not include "new lines" in the output text
- better at reading Chinese (一 and 了 and 。 are often not selectable at all)

For the purpose of copying speech bubbles in Chinese comics. At the moment a bubble like

[image]

can only be copied as

> 个再平凡
> 不过的中考
> 狗

(It should be

> 一个再平凡不过的中考狗。

)

Comment: How can any OCR reader recognize whether a line break is a line break or not?

Comment: @nohillside I would like it to just never include any linebreaks

Comment: There's a difficult gap to bridge between a machine "seeing" characters as they are and translating them as such, and seeing those same characters and writing them as you'd like them to appear.  AI can potentially address this, but it's currently not implemented into Live Text.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any user-configuration for Apple's Live Text.

You can send feedback to Apple about problems with the feature at https://www.apple.com/feedback/

In the meantime, it may be possible to automate the corrections to limit the additional work. Though, in my experience, all OCR-ed text needs some correction.

Answer (score 2):

With Shortcuts as a workaround, copying the Simplified Chinese in the given example has no line breaks:

Capture Text From Screen
https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/3bc2c2e9d2c8487fb1b4328d628ae903

Using the shortcut, the captured result is

> 一个再平凡不过的中考狗。

It works on all applications as long as Screen Recording is enabled. You can also bind the action with a keyboard shortcut for quick access.